# Conditional unpoly modal dialog close

Tags: unpoly

I have a list of items on the page and a link with attribute [up-modal], leading to the page with a form for adding new items to the list. The form opens up in a modal dialog and has attribute [up-target] so it is submitted by Ajax with the help of unpoly.

What I can't figure out is how to close the dialog and update the list of items on the underlying page in case if the form was submitted without errors and if there were errors on the server side I want the dialog to stay opened and show the form with errors.

If I add the attribute [up-sticky] to the link opening the modal dialog, the results of the correctly submitted form appear in the modal dialog instead of being put on the page.

Without [up-sticky] attribute the form with errors after submitting replaces the underlying page.

So how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you have a route `/page-with-list` and a route `/modal-form`.

In `/page-with-list` you had a `<div class="list">...</div>`.

In `/modal-form` I would write the `<form>` like this:

```
<form action="/process-modal-form" up-target=".list" up-layer="page" up-fail-layer="modal">
  ..
</form>
```

This should replace `.list` in the page layer if the form succeeds, but replace the form in the modal layer if it fails. In forms Unpoly will automatically set a `up-fail-target` attribute that matches the form.

Comment: And for this to work we need to send non 200 response header when the form submit failed to let the unpoly know that the form was not submitted.

Comment: I've tried to implement by your advice but it issues me an error "Could not find failure target in current modal (tried ["form", "body"])". And it seems to not send request to the server. But there is a form in the modal, I see it in the chrome's inspector. I even tried to set up-fail-target: main, which is present there too but the error persists, just changes to "Could not find failure target in current modal (tried ["main", "body"])". What can be wrong?

Comment: And one more strange behaviour - in the same modal I have form with attributes up-target: main, up-layer: page, up-fail-layer: modal and below it I have a link "back" with attributes up-target: main, up-layer: page. As I described, when I try to submit the form it doesn't work. But when I later click "back" link under the form, the form is submitted and underlying page's list of items is renewed.

Comment: Oops, I was wrong about it actually sent the request to the server and there was error on the server side, it returned 500 error without main, form and whatever... The request didn't show in the console on the server and that confused me. Anyway, everything works as expected, Thanks!

Comment: @triskweline, is this actual solution for 2.x version of unpoly?

Comment: @okliv No. The overlay model was completely rewritten in Unpoly 2 to better support this very use case.

Comment: @okliv See our documentation on [subinteractions](https://unpoly.com/subinteractions) and check out the [demo](https://demo.unpoly.com/) for examples.

Comment: @triskweline, thanks, will study it. (tried to find subinteractions in website structure/menu - didn't find it. my opinion, unpoly website has to be more structured. a lot of info there are hidden in raw webpage text links and it is difficult to quickly return to it. i can handle this and know what bookmarks are, but if i think from another side i can imagine amount of useful info hidden from user)

Answer (score 1):

And I answer my question here, may be it can be helpful to someone.
So, in my case if the server sends back the page with form on it and the modal dialog is open means that the form was submitted with errors and couldn't be accepted on the server side. To check these conditions and if necessary close the modal dialog and refresh the underlying page I made a script:

```
up.on("up:fragment:inserted", function(ev, fragment) {
    if (up.modal.isOpen() && !fragment.getElementsByTagName("form").length) {
        up.modal.close()
    }
})
up.on("up:modal:closed", function(ev) {
     up.reload("main")
})
```

**EDIT** When I used the described above method it worked ok until I needed to put a content without form into modal. In that case my modal simply opened and instantly closed, so I reworked my previous implementation like this:

```
let submit_from_modal = false;

up.on("up:fragment:inserted", function(ev, fragment) {
    if (up.modal.isOpen() && !fragment.getElementsByTagName("form").length && submit_from_modal) {
        up.modal.close()
        up.emit("modal:form:submit:success")
    }
    submit_from_modal = false
})

up.on("up:modal:close", function() {
    submit_from_modal = false
})

up.on("modal:form:submit:success", function(ev) {
    up.reload("main")
})

up.on("up:form:submit", function() {
    if (up.modal.isOpen()) {
        submit_from_modal = true
    }
})
```